# Wicket ajax call failes after opening page in another tab

Tags: wicket

I have a wicket application. The application is basically a single page application and everything is done using ajax calls. I have a requirement to open a piece of information in another tab or window. There are several ways to do so, using html

```
target = "_blank"
```

or using code via PopupSettings. All these work in way that they open the new page/tab with the data I need.

The problem is that when I click on an ajax action on the origin page, after opening the other window/ tab, I get an error saying the component belongs to a different page. After debugging I understand that once I call the new page, my old page is no longer stored in the page store manager cache. What happens is that on request commit (which is called at the end of the request cycle) the following is called on org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager:

```
public synchronized void setSessionCache(final List<IManageablePage> pages) {
    sessionCache = new ArrayList<>(pages);
    afterReadObject = null;
}
```

with the "pages" list argument holding a single page, the new page, thus replacing the current page in the cache. Once I call the the ajax call, instead of receiving the page from cache I receive a deSerialized version of the page from the store which is a different instance then the one connected to the component used for the click behaviour, and I get the error.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? an architectural flow? Appreciate any light shed on this.

I'm using wicket 8.9.0

Here is the call to the page to render on a new tab. currently it is on a non ajax button inside the page:

```
protected void onClick() {
      UserSession.get().setAttribute(Constants.documentRef, obj);
      this.setResponsePage(DocumentViewPage.class);
}
```

The button tag has target="_blank".

Here is the error I get:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component [RealmPanel [Component id = realm]] cannot be updated because it is on another page.
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PartialPageUpdate.add(PartialPageUpdate.java:451)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestHandler.add(AjaxRequestHandler.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestHandler.add(AjaxRequestHandler.java:234)
    at com.centimia.smartAdmin.frame.controller.Navigator.updateRealm(Navigator.java:474)
    at com.centimia.smartAdmin.frame.controller.Navigator.setCurrentPanel(Navigator.java:249)
    at com.emi.client.main.panel.folder.FolderMenuProvider$3.onClick(FolderMenuProvider.java:179)
    at com.centimia.smartAdmin.frame.component.menu.MenuItem$1.onClick(MenuItem.java:76)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:85)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:127)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:598)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.internalInvoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:306)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:280)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerRequestHandler.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.respond(ListenerRequestHandler.java:208)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:914)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:282)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.AbstractUpgradeFilter.processRequestCycle(AbstractUpgradeFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:206)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid use case and it should work just fine! Please create a min/quickstart application that demonstrates the problem and share it with us (here or in JIRA).

Comment: Ok I accept it is a valid use case. It is too complicated to show a use cse project as the problem basically is with the framework I've developed on top of wicket. I've managed to solve the issue on my end. However I still argue that there is an architectural flaw. There isn't enough "room" in a comment to explain why. Maybe Jira is the right place to make my case....

Comment: JIRA or StackOverflow, either is fine! But without a reproducer there is no way to debug and fix it.